# How to modify product data using ProductPageLoadedEvent in Shopware 6?

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6

Does anyone knows to modify product data using `Shopware\Storefront\Page\Product\ProductPageLoadedEvent` ?

`services.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <service id="Swag\BasicExample\Service\AddDataToPage" >
                <argument type="service" id="product.repository"/>
                <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber" />
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

`AddDataToPage.php`

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Swag\BasicExample\Service;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepositoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Shopware\Storefront\Page\Product\ProductPageLoadedEvent;

class AddDataToPage implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EntityRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * @param EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    )
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @return string[]
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            ProductPageLoadedEvent::class => 'onProductsLoaded'
        ];
    }


    /**
     * @param ProductPageLoadedEvent $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function onProductsLoaded(
        ProductPageLoadedEvent $event
    )
    {
        // the product is inside the page object
        $productData = $event->getPage()->getProduct();


        //modifying name
        $this->log($productData->getName());
        $productData->setName('Prefix Product Name' . $productData->getName());
        $this->log($productData->getName());


        //modifying ManufacturerNumber
        $this->log($productData->getManufacturerNumber());
        $productData->setManufacturerNumber('Prefix ManufacturerNumber' . $productData->getManufacturerNumber());
        $this->log($productData->getManufacturerNumber());

        $event->getPage()->setProduct($productData);

    }

    /**
     * @param $message
     * @return void
     */
    private function log($message)
    {
        $logFileName = 'someFile.log';
        file_put_contents(
            $logFileName,
            $message . PHP_EOL,
            FILE_APPEND
        );
    }
}
```

After modifying the above mentioned changes it still shows the original data although
`$event->getPage()->setProduct($productData);`

I'm in doubt whether `ProductPageLoadedEvent` is an after dispatching event or before dispatching the event.

Comment: I have tested your code and it works. You don't even have to set the product because `$productData` is a reference to the product object. So you can delete the line `$event->getPage()->setProduct($productData);`. Did you check if your plugin is active? Did you clear the cache?

Comment: yes, cleared the cache. Just to add further changes are logged to the log file but not reflected on the product detail page with changes. Tried without the `$event->getPage()->setProduct($productData);` line as well but no luck.

Comment: Do you use a custom layout for your product detail page? Is there the element `<div class="cms-element-product-name">` in your html code?

Comment: In recent Shopware versions there are two groups of templates for the product page: One if a custom layout is selected and a older version for non-custom layouts (which will, I believe, be removed sooner or later). This is a common cause for errors if template changes don't apply: Then maybe the wrong templates were used. This can also be verified via the dev-toolbar.

Comment: DId you solve this?

Comment: yes @Alex it is solved now. The issue might be with name translation as I was trying to set the `name`. I override `setManufacturerNumber` which works great.